# Multithreads executando a mesma função em paralelo

Tags: c, paralelismo

Estou tentando fazer com que esse código execute a função calculaPrimo() em cada thread paralelamente para achar numeros primos em um intervalo de 1 até o valor maximo passado via command line, por exemplo se o usuario colocar o valor maximo como 100 e o numero de threads maximas como 2 eu queria fazer com que a thread 1 analisasse os numeros: 1,3,5... e a thread 2 os numeros:2,4,6... porem o que está acontecendo é que cada thread ta percorrendo novamente o intervalo resultando nessa saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue o código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *calculaPrimo(void *limitValue) {
    int primo, j;
    int num = 1;
    int maxValue = *(int*)limitValue;

    while (num <= maxValue) {
        primo = 1;

        for (j = 2; j < num && primo; j++) {
            if (num % j == 0) {
                primo = 0;
            }
        }
        if (primo == 1) {
            printf("%d ", num);
        }
        num++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    return NULL;
}

void criaThreads(char* const* args) {
    int maxValue;
    int maxThreads;
    long t;
    pthread_t *threads;

    maxValue = atoi(args[1]);
    maxThreads = atoi(args[2]);

    printf("Maximum integer   %d\n", maxValue);
    printf("Number of threads %d\n", maxThreads);
    
    threads = (pthread_t *)calloc(sizeof(pthread_t), maxThreads);

    for (t = 0; t < maxThreads; t++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, calculaPrimo, &maxValue);
    }

    for (t = 0; t < maxThreads; t++) {
        pthread_join(threads[t],NULL);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* const* argv) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("%s: insufficient parameters. Please inform maximum value and number of threads\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    criaThreads(argv);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mas essas threads sequer estão trabalhando de forma paralela? No seu console elas parecem estar imprimindo os resultados sequencialmente, se estivessem executando em paralelo os valores seriam imprimidos de forma intercalada.

Comment: Me parece que todas as threads estão recebendo o mesmo parâmetro maxValue, então é esperado que todas repitam o mesmo trabalho.